# Distinct DNS for two VLANs using Dnsmasq and FreshTomato

Tags: router, dns, dhcp, vlan, dnsmasq

I have two VLANs on my router and am trying to serve distinct DNS to each of them. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467430/dnsmasq-tags-and-conditional-dns-server) that shows a user trying to accomplish something similar.

I've done research before finding that thread and only find similar solutions or scripted solutions that won't work in my case (since I am using whatever version of Dnsmasq that is bundled with FreshTomato v2023.3). When I try to save the configuration, it tells me that there is a disruptive syntax error. If I remove the third and fourth lines I don't get the message so it is obviously okay with the first and second lines:

```
dhcp-range=set:net1,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.32,infinite
dhcp-range=set:net2,192.168.2.2,192.168.2.32,infinite
dhcp-option=tag:net1,option:dns-server,91.239.100.100,2001:67c:28a4::
dhcp-option=tag:net2,option:dns-server,89.233.43.71,2a01:3a0:53:53::
```

I've tried removing the ipv6 servers and have tried changing "option:dns-server" to "6" with the same results.